# How do I use class to trigger functions for multiple elements onmouseover and onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onmouseover

I have this code that is working. Basically it is to play sound onclick and onmouseover. But I have to use it on many elements (links and images). I want a solution that can enable me use class instead of onmouseover and onclick within the html page. I think it's something like event listeners but I find it hard to pull it off.

Here is my code below

```js
var audio, clicksound, hoversound, mutebtn;
function initAudioPlayer(){
  audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = ("audio.ogg", "audio.mp3");
  audio.loop = false;
  audio.volume = 0.5;
  audio.play();

  clicksound = new Audio();
  clicksound.src = ("audio/click.ogg", "click.mp3");
  clicksound.loop = false;
  clicksound.volume = 0.5;
  clicksound.play();

  hoversound = new Audio();
  hoversound.src = ("audio/hover.ogg", "hover.mp3");
  hoversound.loop = false;
  hoversound.volume = 0.5;
  hoversound.play();

  mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");

  mutebtn.addEventListener("click", mute);

  mutebtn.addEventListener("click", muteclick);

  mutebtn.addEventListener("click", mutehover);

  function mute(){
    if(audio.muted){
        audio.muted = false;
        mutebtn.style.background = "url(images/speaker.png) no-repeat";
      } else {
        audio.muted = true;
        mutebtn.style.background = "url(images/muted.png) no-repeat";
      }
  }

  function muteclick(){
    if(clicksound.muted){
        clicksound.muted = false;
        mutebtn.style.background = "url(images/speaker.png) no-repeat";
      } else {
        clicksound.muted = true;
        mutebtn.style.background = "url(images/muted.png) no-repeat";
      }
  }

  function mutehover(){
    if(hoversound.muted){
        hoversound.muted = false;
        mutebtn.style.background = "url(images/speaker.png) no-repeat";
      } else {
        hoversound.muted = true;
        mutebtn.style.background = "url(images/muted.png) no-repeat";
      }
  }

}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Just a sample code snippet</title>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="#" onmouseover="hoversound.play()" onclick="clicksound.play()">Link 1 of 50+</a></p>

<p><a href="#" onmouseover="hoversound.play()" onclick="clicksound.play()">Link 2 of 50+</a></p>

<p><a href="#" onmouseover="hoversound.play()" onclick="clicksound.play()">Link 3 of 50+</a></p>

<p><a href="#" onmouseover="hoversound.play()" onclick="clicksound.play()">Link 4 of 50+</a></p>

<button onmouseover="audio.play()" onclick="clicksound.play()">Play Audio Sound</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", ( event ) => {
    const hoverElement = event.target;
    if( hoverElement.classList.contains('desiredClass') ){
        // Do somethig
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am new to Javascript and don't understand how to implement your code especially where you commented // Do something. Please can you help to integrate it into my javascript code as shown in my post?